# Normalised database with one-to-one relationship

Tags: database-design

Is it bad practice to use a 1-1 relationship between two logically distinct tables: the user details and the user configuration settings? Each configuration record would have a single unique user ID, but they seemed separate enough to warrant two tables rather than one big one. I ask because [the WikiBook for my school course](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing_2009/AQA/The_Computing_Practical_Project/Technical_Solution#.28Object_Orientation.29_Make_sure_you_use_Encapsulation_appropriately) said that I should only use 1-Many relationships.

In the User table I will be storing details such as their username, id and authorisation token for an external system. In the Config table I will be storing settings such as whether to show a welcome message, which are changeable through the settings page.

Comment: Should give more information on the attributes that you need/want to store in 2 tables. Also can a user have multiple configuration settings?

Comment: You did say they both have user ID as a key.

Comment: @Marco, updated to explain the purpose of each table. Each user will have exactly one configuration record.

Answer (score -1):

The attributes should be split in 2 tables because the configuration details are not depending on the user but on the configuration of an external system. If a user can have only 1 configuration then you must use an 1-1 relation. If a user can have multiple configurations then you must use the 1-M relation.

This is the theory. If you want (in case of a 1-1 relation) put all in 1 table than this is also 'allowed'. Remember well that if one day the relation becomes 1-M that you are in problems. This is also why it is preferred to split the information into 2 tables.

Comment: To be equivocal: According to *theory* there's nothing wrong with either a single table or two 1:1 tables (as in "this is also 'allowed'"), and having a separate table "because the configuration details are not depending on the user" is an *erogonomic/changeablility* reason (as in "This is also why it is preferred to split"). Sadly, typical DBMSs don't let one define the necessary FKs both ways for the 1:1.) (For reasons of not understanding theory.)